# Flag weight displayed wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-profile-page, flagging

I just remarked that my flag weight is shown as `510.0000` instead of `510`. Has anyone else seen the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Also see this related post and answers: [Flag weight 750 reached?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached)

Comment: another related question on meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82437/flag-weight-of-510-0000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flag weights above 500 are by design displayed with four digits after the comma. Up to a weight of 500, a "helpful" flag increases the flag weight by 10, but for higher weights, the increase for a helpful flag is less than 10 -- IIRC, it is exactly 1 for a weight of 625 and 0.1 for the maximum flag weight of 750. Because of the somewhat counter-intuitive formula, a helpful flag at a weight of 500 yields "510.0000", but your next helpful flag will let you advance to somewhat below 520, and the digits after the comma will become useful.

Comment: for the formula see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-many-flags-to-reach-750-flag-weight

Answer (score 7):

This is no bug, it is a normal behaviour. Quoting the [meta.stackoverflow.com post "What is flag weight?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178):

> ### Why is my flag weight not an integer?
>
> Because flag weight above 500 does not increase in a linear fashion,
>   decimal places are shown for precision purposes and to show you how
>   your flag weight is changing.